# Click event is sent immediately after I start application (PySide and Python)

Tags: python, pyside, qfiledialog

I have an application with a button for which the *clicked* signal is connected to a slot that opens a *QFileDialog*. I want to manipulate the state of the button (sender) within the slot depending on the actions taken by the user in the *QFileDialog*.

However, with the code I have presently, my application do not starts correctly. It starts immediately with *QFileDialogOpen* and I do not understand why. When I comment the line that connect the button's clicked signal to the slot, the application starts normally though.

How can I correctly pass the button as an argument when I want to connect a *clicked*  signal of a button to a slot? Here is a MCWE of my problem:

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys

class MyApplication(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        self.fileButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Select File')
        self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file(self.fileButton))

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.fileButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def select_file(self, button):
        file_name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if str(file_name[0]) is not "":
            button.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            button.setDisabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyApplication()    
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: are you sure the code is not in your `__init__` method

Comment: @danidee It is, but it's not clicked.

Comment: something must be calling the method without your knowledge, methods don't just run by themself, try changing the name of your method to see if it still occurs, if i'm right you should get an error saying the old method is not defined

Comment: Or add more code or a traceback or something to the question so this becomes answerable instead of a guessing game

Comment: @danidee Thanks, you got me on a right track. I changed the name and saw my error in traceback. `self.select_file` should be without parenthesis in `self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file())` . But how do I pass parameter then which is a button name?

Comment: use lambda to pass extra arguments `self.fileButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_file(extra_args))`

Comment: @HrvojeT Connect your signal to the slot like this `self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file)` then remove the *button* argument in your method *select_file*. You can get who sent the signal by doing `button = self.sender()` within the *select file* method. Moreover, why are you disabling your button if no file is selected? How your user can select a file if they by mistake close the dialog window?

Comment: @HrvojeT Moreover, you can setup you dialog like that: `fname, ftype = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`. The *getOpenFileName* method already return a string, so you can directly write: `if fname:` instead of `if str(file_name[0]) is not "":`

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien

you helped me a lot, thanks! I'm not good in english so I didn't explain my question well but you answered anyway ;)

Comment: I disabled a button for final calculation when a file is not selected. Not the button for selecting (browsing) a file.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. danidee solution using lambda to pass an extra argument to the built-in signal would work then. Another approach would be to make the button "calculate" a class widget by adding "self" when creating it (`self.buttonCalc = QtGui.QPushButton()`) and by directly accessing it from within your *select_file* method (`self.buttonCalc.setEnabled(True)`).

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I did what you say. I made it a class widget. I want to QLabel writes a file name that a button selects. It woorks fine now. However, another class inherits from this class. I made there the same button and the same label. The button opens QDialog and selects a file but QLabel does not write it. Here is my github repository https://github.com/hrvoojex/telecom-toplist I have to try Alexsander's advice yet

Comment: I've made some comment about your code structure here: https://github.com/hrvoojex/telecom-toplist/issues/1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't bind an actual function **call** using PySide signals/slots, you bind a **function**, **method**, or **function-like object** using PySide's signals/slots.

You have:

```
self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file(self.fileButton))
```

This tells Qt to bind the click event to something that is returned from the self.select_file function call, which presumably has no **__call__** attribute and is called immediately (causing the opening of the QFileDialog)

What you want is the following:

```
from functools import partial
self.fileButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.select_file, self.fileButton))
```

This creates a callable, frozen function-like object with arguments for Qt to call.

This is comparable to saying:

```
self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file)
```

Rather than saying:

```
self.fileButton.clicked.connect(self.select_file())
```

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I had the same issue when I started working with PySide, so I remember the frustration.